# Why supra-conductivity became super-conductivity?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, history, superconductivity

The original article by the Kamerlingh Onnes team in Leiden does not give a name to the new effect:

> Kamerlingh Onnes, H. *Further experiments with liquid helium. C. On the change of electric resistance of pure metals at very low temperatures, etc. V. The disappearance of the resistance of mercury*. KNAW / Comm. Phys. Lab. Univ. Leiden 14 I, 115–122, Comm. 122b (1911).

(note I'm not even sure the title is the orginal one, I'm not sure the paper was in english, since KNAW refers to. I never put a hand on it...)

Few years latter, the name *supra*-conductivity was coined:

> Kamerlingh Onnes, H. *Further experiments with liquid helium. IX. The appearance of galvanic resistance in supraconductor, which are brought into a magnetic field at a threshold value of the field.* KNAW / Comm. Phys. Lab. Univ. Leiden 16 II, 987–992, Comm. 139f (1914).

And the name stayed for a while, for instance in german articles:

> Meissner, W. & Ochsenfeld, R. *Ein neuer Effekt bei Eintritt der Supraleitfähigkeit.* Naturwissenschaften 21, 787 (1933).
>
> London, F. & London, H. *Supraleitung und Diamagnetismus*. Physica 2, 341 (1935).

or when it was about discussing this in english

> London, F. & London, H. *The electromagnetic equations of the supraconductor.* Proc. Roy. Soc. Lond. A 149, 71–88 (1935).
>
> Schrödinger, E. *Phenomenological Theory of Supra-conductivity*. Nature 137, 824–824 (1936).

But it has been changed to *super*-conductivity at some point, for instance in the London book

> London, F. *Superfluids, volume I: Macroscopic theory of superconductivity*. (Dover Publications, Inc., 1961).

I wonder why...

Comment: note that it's still called *Supraleitung* in German (and *supraconductivité* in French)

Comment: ...which you apparently [already know](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/82390/6389)

Comment: This beautifully written soft-question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be about linguistics rather than actual physics.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, I believe you're right. Maybe there is something more conceptual than the simple linguistics issue. In English, both super- and supra- prefixes exist. When I wrote it, I thought it was similar to this other question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71759/16689   Nevertheless, feel free to move it to a more relevant place. Perhaps English-Language-and-Usage SE would be better: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Christoph Even if I already knew, thanks for pointing this out :-)